# Overlapping images in HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table, overlap

Can someone explain why the images are overlapping?

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5">
 <tr>
  <td width="20%"><div class="smallfont"><a href="link1"><b>Nymphomaniac: Vol. II<br></br>(2013)</b></a></div>
   <div style="position:relative; left:0; top:0;">
    <img src="http://static.rogerebert.com/uploads/movie/movie_poster/nymphomaniac-vol-i-2014/large_3lVe9Os8FjpX1VgtdT9VFnbqs5f.jpg" style="z-index:1; position:absolute; left:10px; top:0;" width="150" height="230"/>
    <img src="http://s2.postimg.org/wl6fn18ft/moldura.png" style="z-index:2;position:absolute; left:0; top:0;"/>
    <img src="http://s27.postimg.org/njcn0o0vn/player.png" style="z-index:3;position:absolute; left:0; top:0; opacity: 0;" onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100" onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0;this.filters.alpha.opacity=0"/>
    </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="20%"><div class="smallfont"><a href="link2"><b>Nymphomaniac: Vol. II<br></br>(2013)</b></a></div>
   <div style="position:relative; left:0; top:0;">
    <img src="http://static.rogerebert.com/uploads/movie/movie_poster/nymphomaniac-vol-i-2014/large_3lVe9Os8FjpX1VgtdT9VFnbqs5f.jpg" style="z-index:1; position:absolute; left:10px; top:0;" width="150" height="230"/>
    <img src="http://s2.postimg.org/wl6fn18ft/moldura.png" style="z-index:2;position:absolute; left:0; top:0;"/>
    <img src="http://s27.postimg.org/njcn0o0vn/player.png" style="z-index:3;position:absolute; left:0; top:0; opacity: 0;" onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100" onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0;this.filters.alpha.opacity=0"/>
    </div>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Example Image:

[image]

Comment: What do you want the output to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that`<div>` tags which contain `<img>` tags don't have *width* and *height* attributes at the same time `<img>` has *width* and *height*.
so if you add next css code:

```
<style>
    div.photodiv{
        width: 150px;
        height: 230px;  
    }
</style>
```

and then you are going to add `class="photodiv"`to `<div>` elements which contain `<img>` inside it.
here are all the code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
    div.photodiv{
        width: 150px;
        height: 230px;


    }
</style>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5">
     <tr>
        <td width="20%">
            <div class="smallfont"><a href="link1"><b>Nymphomaniac: Vol. II<br></br>(2013)</b></a></div>
            <div class="photodiv" style="position:relative; left:0; top:0;">
                <img src="http://static.rogerebert.com/uploads/movie/movie_poster/nymphomaniac-vol-i-2014/large_3lVe9Os8FjpX1VgtdT9VFnbqs5f.jpg" style="z-index:1; position:absolute; left:10px; top:0;" width="150" height="230"/>
                <img src="http://s2.postimg.org/wl6fn18ft/moldura.png" style="z-index:2;position:absolute; left:0; top:0;"/>
                <img src="http://s27.postimg.org/njcn0o0vn/player.png" style="z-index:3;position:absolute; left:0; top:0; opacity: 0;" onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100" onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0;this.filters.alpha.opacity=0"/>
            </div>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td width="20%">
            <div class="smallfont"><a href="link2"><b>Nymphomaniac: Vol. II<br></br>(2013)</b></a></div>
            <div class="photodiv" style="position:relative; left:0; top:0;">
                <img src="http://static.rogerebert.com/uploads/movie/movie_poster/nymphomaniac-vol-i-2014/large_3lVe9Os8FjpX1VgtdT9VFnbqs5f.jpg" style="z-index:1; position:absolute; left:10px; top:0;" width="150" height="230"/>
                <img src="http://s2.postimg.org/wl6fn18ft/moldura.png" style="z-index:2;position:absolute; left:0; top:0;"/>
                <img src="http://s27.postimg.org/njcn0o0vn/player.png" style="z-index:3;position:absolute; left:0; top:0; opacity: 0;" onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100" onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0;this.filters.alpha.opacity=0"/>
            </div>
        </td>
     </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to add some css to the code so add

```
<style>
    #poster{
       padding-bottom:230px;
    }
</style>
```

Then you are going to add `id="poster"` to the first `<div class="smallfont">`, making it `<div class="small font" id="poster">`